# set shell = powershell. But I want to use the Anaconda powershell

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, powershell

Is there any way to use the `Anaconda powershell` instead of the standard `Windows powershell`?

In my `.vimrc` I have

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-command
```

Running on `Vim 9` for `Windows`.

Comment: `let &shell = "C:\\\\link\\\\to\\\\Anaconda\\\\powershell.exe"`. NOTE the quadruple backslashes. Escaping once isn't enough here.

Comment: @kadekai if you use single quotes would a single escape (`'C:\\link\\to…'`) work?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes. I use double quotes here for a personal and unrelated reason. Forgot that when commenting. Otherwise, single quote is more suitable here. (For others, see `:h literal-strings`).